# Cordova plugin in Angular 4 Typescript application

Tags: cordova, angular, typescript

I want to use the `cc.fovea.cordova.purchase` plugin in an Angular4 application + Cordova.

I added the plugin to `config.xml`:

```
<platform name="android">
    ...
    <plugin name="cc.fovea.cordova.purchase" spec="https://github.com/j3k0/cordova-plugin-purchase.git">
        <param name="BILLING_KEY" value="XXX"/>
    </plugin>
</platform>
```

I also added `typed-cordova-plugin-purchase` to `devDependencies` in `package.json` and to `typeRoots` in `tsconfig.json`.

When I'm trying

```
import { store, IStore, IProduct } from "cc.fovea.cordova.purchase";
```

I get

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'cc.fovea.cordova.purchase'

What is the correct way of using a Cordova plugin in an Angular 4 Typescript app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had to do one more thing, add `node_modules/typed-cordova-plugin-purchase` to `typeRoots` and `typed-cordova-plugin-purchase` to `types` in `tsconfig.json`.

Comment: Is there any example on how to make it work? I added the plugin with: typings install github:werk85/typed-cordova-plugin-purchase --global --save and cordova plugin add cc.fovea.cordova.purchase , but still can't import.