# How to integrate angular 2+ into a cordova project

Tags: angular, cordova

I want to use angular 2+ and cordova together in a single project. I followed this tutorial https://medium.com/@EliaPalme/how-to-wrap-an-angular-app-with-apache-cordova-909024a25d79 but don't understand where to put angular, because I want to have them together in the same project. Is it possible to have them together (I don't want to use Ionic but want to use angular features and cordova plugins together)?

Comment: A simple way is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52602342/angular-6-cordova-how-to-convert-current-angular-project-to-cordova-based-pr/52603564#52603564 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528481/how-to-use-cordova-plugin-in-a-typescript-cordova-project/54529787#54529787 to add plugings or control back-button, e.g. But it's only has an Angular aplication that "copy" in a Cordova project. I don't know if it is your'e looking for

Comment: Thank you Eliseo for the answer. I'll explain it better. I need to build a mobile hybrid app (using Cordova to access device like have local notifications thus using local notifications plugin) and want to build presentation view  of the app with latest angular version. So I want to know if it is possible to have a unique project where I can work with typescript and use cordova plugins, and to build only one project like you can do with a Ionic project (but I don't want to use Ionic). I hope I explained it better :).