# Pause and Resume events - Cordova & Angular8

Tags: angular, cordova

I am currently attempting to use the `pause` and `resume` events for a Cordova + Angular 8 application.

```html
constructor() {
    document.addEventListener("pause", this.buttonPressed, false);
    document.addEventListener("resume", this.powerTestSuccess, false);
}

buttonPressed(){
    this.pressed = true;
    console.log('PAUSE EVENT RUNNING');
}

powerTestSuccess(){
   setTimeout(function() {
       console.log("RESUME EVENT RUNNING");
       console.log(this.pressed);
       if(this.pressed == true){
           this.doSomething();
       } else {
           this.doSomethingElse();
       }
   }, 0);
}
```

I can see thethe console.logs are working, however the `this.pressed` is not being manipulated and also the `doSomething()` & `doSomethingElse()` functions are not being ran. I read in the cordova documentation that `When called from a resume event handler, interactive functions such as alert() need to be wrapped in a setTimeout() call with a timeout value of zero, or else the app hangs.`

Is this the reason why nothing except the `console.log` is working?

What can I do to get this working?

Comment: It's a litle old, but I like use a service and the component subscribe to the service, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54528481/how-to-use-cordova-plugin-in-a-typescript-cordova-project/54529787#54529787

Comment: does calling `doSomethingElse()` throw an error??

Comment: No errors, when calling `doSomethingElse()` in other functions it's fine.

Comment: @Eliseo The problem isnt getting the pause and  resume events working as these are fine. It's more the fact that nothing inside the function  is working apart from `console.log` when called from the events.

Comment: @LewisBrowne, ::glup:: your'e correct. I added a answer with some that work and a sugestion that I don't know if work. If you check this last, can you say me if it's ok to improve the post?

Answer (score 1):

::glups::, you need use ngZone
Imagine you has a service like

```
export enum CordovaEvent {BackButton,Resume,Pause}
@Injectable()

export class CordovaEventService {

    private listeningSource:Subject<CordovaEvent>=new Subject<CordovaEvent>();
    cordovaEvent:Observable<CordovaEvent>=this.listeningSource.asObservable();
    isCordoba:boolean=false;
    constructor() {
    }

    sendEvent(evento:CordovaEvent)
    {
        this.listeningSource.next(evento);
    }
}
```

//In your app.main

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady.bind(this), false);
  }
  onDeviceReady() {
    // Control pause, resume and backbutton
    document.addEventListener('pause', this.onPause.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener('resume', this.onResume.bind(this), false);
    document.addEventListener("backbutton", this.onBackKeyDown.bind(this), false);
    this.cordovaEventService.isCordoba=true;

  };

  onPause() {
    this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.Pause);
  };

  onResume() {
    this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.Resume);
  };

  onBackKeyDown(e) {
    this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.BackButton);
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

  };
```

In a component, you can subscribe to "cordovaEvent" I use a "clasic" takeWhile() to unsubscribe, a variable `alive:boolean=true`, and in ngOnDestroy `this.alive=false`

```
this.cordovaEventService.cordovaEvent.pipe(takeWhile(() => this.alive))
  .subscribe((event: CordovaEvent) => {
  if (event == CordovaEvent.BackButton) {
    //An event that no need has reflecj in Angular not need run in ngZone
    if (this.pagina=="Home") {
      navigator.notification.confirm("Do you really quit out?", 
            this.onConfirm, "App-example", ["OK", "Cancel"]);
    }
    else
    {
      this.ngZone.run(()=>{
        !--make some thing--
      })
    }
  }
});
```

Well, this work because I checked, but imagine that -not check- we improve the servcie running in a ngZone the own service, change the functions onPause, onResumen and onBackButton

```
  onPause() {
      this.ngZone.run(()=>{
         this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.Pause);
      })
  };

  onResume() {
    this.ngZone.run(()=>{
       this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.Resume);
    })
  };

  onBackKeyDown(e) {
    this.ngZone.run(()=>{
        this.cordovaEventService.sendEvent(CordovaEvent.BackButton);
      })
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

  };
```